# How to maintain a Session info in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have script like below:

```
foreach ($var1 in (gc 1.txt)){
 // my code logic
}
```

Here 1.txt file contains list of values like abc, xyz, pqr etc..,
If due to any of the script issues/ctrl+c stopped the script, need to restart the script from last stopped session.
To be clear if script has stopped at processing file at 'xyz' and when i restart the script it should process the logic from 'xyz' only but shouldn't restart from 'abc' again.

Please guide me to achieve this logic.

Thanks in advance,
Pavan kumar D

Comment: Use a ´for´ loop and save the processing index on a file.

Comment: No need to for-next loop, although that is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some counters and keep track of last iteration using and index file.

Then make sure that you start reading the file where you was interrupted using `select -Skip`

```
<#
.NOTE
    The file index.txt is created at the first run and is used to store 
    the last line accessed of the file to process.

    The index read from index.txt is used to skip by already processed 
    lines at the start of the foreach.

    If the index doesn't need to be stored between session, then use
    a $global.index instead to speed up the script, instead of an index 
    file (or a RAM-drive, not very common any more).

    At each succefull iteration, the index is incremented and then stored in 
    index.txt.

    When starting the stored index.txt is compared with the numbers of 
    lines in the file and will through an error if it's passed End Of File.

    Make sure to **clear** the index.txt before starting the file process 
    fresh.
#>

#initialize counters
[int]$StartLine = Get-Content .\index.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (-not $StartLine){[int]$StartLine = 0} # First run will have no index file
$Index = $StartLine
[int]$LastLineOfFile = (get-content 1.txt).count - 1 # Arrays starts at 0

if ($Index -gt $LastLineOfFile){# Don't start if index passed EOF at last run
    Write-Error "Index passed end of file"
    return
}

foreach ($var in (Get-Content 1.txt | Select -Skip $StartLine)){
    
    "New loop: $Index" | Out-Host # will start empty

    "Processing value: $var" | Out-Host

    ####
    # Processing here
    ####

    "Done processing value: $var" | Out-Host

    $Index++ 
    $Index > index.txt
    "Index incremented" | Out-Host
}
```

For a good article of using RAM drive, see, i.e. [How to Create RAM Disk in Windows 10 for Super-Fast Read and Write Speeds](https://beebom.com/create-ram-disk-windows-10-super-fast-read-write-speeds/)

Windows Server do support RAM disks natively (kind of) by using the iSCSI Target Server.
See, [How to Create a RAM Disk on Windows Server?](http://howto.hyonix.com/article/how-to-create-a-ram-disk-on-windows-server/)

Comment: Excellent Dennis, it worked. Thanks. Can we maintain the comparison of the line text at the same time So that if any new text has been added in middle of the text file,we won't process it. To be precise, if lines are in sequence, ex:- abc,xyz,etc.., for this the given logic is good and if we added text in middle like ex:- abc,ghi,xyz, etc., in this case also we shouldn't process abc and xyz but only ghi. Please help me with this.                  Thanks in advance

Comment: If the file has been altered since a break (if that is the question), then I suggest the whole file to be reprocessed...

Comment: yes Dennis, but rather than reprocessing whole file, shall we compare the content in text file like if the 'abc' existed in the return file which we are writing after process done, then it shouldn't process and move to next line. because we have the source file which contains hundreds of repository names. for ex: by altering 2 repo names into source file, it would take from scratch again to process those 2 which would repeat all the repos processing again. Can you please suggest me the best way to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe you could mark the processed files as done? Either by labeling, moving them or keeping a done file along with the index file?

Comment: Yes, Dennis. That's what i need. As you suggested, If we label as "$var, done" > index.txt file. How can we validate from the loop variable for skipping which was labelled as done and process for the next iteration? Please help with some snippet

Comment: I think we are out of scope of the original question... Try setting up a new question about this new requirement.

Comment: sure Dennis, will mark it as a solution and create  new one. Thanks

Comment: similar question added here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69016336/how-to-maintain-a-session-by-validating-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-powershel