# How to maintain a session by validating each line in a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This is my sample code below:

```
foreach ($var1 in (gc 1.txt)){
 // my code logic
}
```

Here 1.txt file contains list of values like abc, xyz, pqr etc..,like 100 lines in 1.txt file for processing one by one. After processing got completed for 100 lines, there is a new value altered in middle for processing and the count now is 101 lines. Now i need to restart the script and should process newly added value rather than starting from the scratch.
Actually for this requirement there are hundreds of lines are there in my project.
Can you please suggest me the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My approach would probably be to keep state which would include all the lines in the file.  I might try using `Select-String` for this which includes line numbers and the line itself.  Then on each check compare the old state data to the new state data checking line and line numbers somehow.  Could possibly use `Compare-Object` for this but not sure if that's the best route or not.  Worth a shot.  `$newLogData = Select-String -Path $log -Pattern .*; $newLogData | Export-Clixml $oldDataFile; Compare-Object $logData $newLogData -Property LineNumber, Line`

Comment: Can you explain a little bit deeper why already created files are changed? Are we talking about live data that are supposed to be altered at any time?

Comment: Yes Dennis, Actually the text file using in the loop is the output of API(which will extract repositories),so if anyone has created new repo it will append into this text file. we are using this list of repositories for scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - saving a snapshot of the file and comparing it to the current list:

```
# Import values and list of completed updates
$ToUpdate  = Get-Content list.txt
$Completed = Get-Content completed.txt

# Take a snapshot for next run
Copy-Item -Path list.txt -Destination completed.txt -Force

# use Compare to determine which updates are new
$Unprocessed = Compare-Object $ToUpdate $Completed | 
    where SideIndicator -EQ '<=' | 
    Select -ExpandProperty InputObject

Foreach ($var1 in $Unprocessed) {
  # Do Stuff
}
```

Ideally, you want to check against your actual target instead of a log file. If you're updating a database/user directory/grocery list, query that instead, because otherwise you can run into issues. What if something else updates the target while you're not looking? What if your script errors out and doesn't actually complete all the updates? Something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cpt.Whale.It's really helped